Generate illustrations without sharp rectangular boundary
I am using AI to generate illustrations. I am interested in illustrations without a discernible rectangular border. Few examples;

As a plus, there are elements on the edges which are complete but stick out of the overall boundary.
My images almost always have a rectangular edge.

The only question related to this that I could find is this, and I have gone through the suggestions, but it was not helpful.
What is this even called? What is this feature/style called? What keywords could I search for? Or what prompt is required?

It all heavily depends on what particular AI you are using and how you are using it. Currently the commercial AI engines are typically a bit limitted in how much you can adjust the result.
So one thing you can do is start out with a image, then ask the AI to mutate that image. This is most likey a bit too strong of an effect.
The second thing that you can do is ask the ai to describe the image. This however is a bit of a hit and miss. Generally prompting is the least able to do layout decissions one of the functions.
Next you search for a model that is specifically trained or modifed for the effect you are looking for. Something like this lora for stable diffusion should make it considerably easier.
Then you use something like control net, or style transfer for this. Both of these are more like the image transform but allow you to reconfigure the image more, such ss ignoring color or allowing you to use a sketch as a basis.
then you should consider just painting roughly over generated result and let the ai redraw the thing with moderate denoising.
If this fails you can train your own model. Three images is entirely plausible if you just modify an underlying model. Shouldnt take too much time.

You can take the image and ask Copilot or another service to describe the image. This will help you get a prompt
Example, "I want to generate an image similar to this one. Describe a prompt I would use in DALL-E 3 to achieve this."
Then use the prompt to draw a new image. You may want to add text like "Vector Illustration Badge"
Example image using the 3rd image as a reference image.


That's one fat tire! Would need some manual reworking. But besides that it seems to get what the OP wants.

The one word that made a difference was 'badge' especially in dall-e but then it tends to ignore instructions about the rest of the style. Badges always seems to have heavy strokes and few muted colors.

in some apps keywords such as "sticker", "t-shirt design" or similar also work well
